Ошибка при объявлении большого массива в Fortran
При объявлении массива происходит ошибка компиляции, иногда компилятор пишет что стек переполнен, иногда вообще без пояснений. Заметил, что когда массив начинает занимать примерно 1,8 Гб оперативной памяти, тогда ошибка и происходит. В теории на 64-битных системах максимальный размер массива на языке Fortran может достигать 2^63-1, но у меня размер меньше. Проект создаю тоже 64-разрядный. Использую компилятор Intel Fortran. Выдаёт такую ошибку:

Compilation Aborted (code 1)

Код программы:
Program Console1
real*8:: arr1(250000000)
pause
end program Console1 


какой фортран используется? как объявляешь массив?

Без кода не гадаем. Приложите код, приложите все ошибки, вся инфа должна быть в вопросе. А система у вас точно 64-битная? А сам Fortran 64-битный? А оперативной памяти сколько свободно?

Использу компилятор Intel Fortran 2023 года в Visual Studio 2022. Всего имею 16 Гб оперативной памяти, 10 из них свободны. Система 64-битная точно, проект тоже

Ладно, если с размером опечатка, то может и не в размере памяти дело.

Вот сам голову второй день ломаю почему так происходит

Ну всё-таки сам то Fortran 64-битный? И он настроен на 64-битную компиляцию? А, видимо, всё же да. Ну я бы перепроверил всё-таки настройки.

Да, конечно способен

Немного вангования (ничего не знаю про фортран) - возможно при таком объявлении массив создается на стеке, а размер стека очень ограничен. Возможно есть создание массивов в куче (аналог malloc в С).

Если честно, не знаю даже что такое стек и куча. Правильно ли я понимаю, что разница в области оперативной памяти, где идёт выделение, и чисто теоретически, если поменять эту область, то ошибка может разрешиться?

allocatable?

А, еще про глобальную память я забыл. Условно, когда вы в Си создаете массив фиксированного размера внутри функции - он создается в стеке (стек - временное хранилище для локальных переменных, адресов возврата), его размер очень ограничен. Когда вы создаете массив глобально (вне функции) - его размер ограничен только размером свободной оперативной памяти. Ну и третий способ - вы создаете массив "принудительно", явным выделением памяти, тут размер тоже ограничен только размером свободной памяти. Специфику фортрана не знаю, так что тут могу только предполагать, как может быть.

Всем спасибо за помощь!

Для Fortran программ Windows/Unix/macOS обычно используют: сегмент данных - инициализированные массивы отличными от 0 данными, сегмент BSS - массивы фиксированного размера для нерекурсивных подпрограмм (возможно, инициалированные 0), стек - массивы переменного размера в подпрограммах, а так же все массивы рекурсивных подпрограмм (если их размер не превышает /heap-arrays), куча - массивы с явным или неявным атрибутом allocatable.

Действительно, проблема была в маленьком стеке. Для того, чтобы создать большой массив, нужно сделать его динамическим и сразу же выделить под него память:
Program Console1 
real*8, allocatable:: arr1(:)
allocate(arr1(250000000))
pause
end program Console1 

Получилось выделить даже память под массив с 5 000 000 000 элеметов

Интересно, это же уже 40Гб памяти нужно, свапует он их что ли средствами операционки

@CrazyElf, выделить 40Гб адресного пространства не значит выделить под него 40Гб памяти. Вот если/когда попытаться её заполнить, то тут-то и начнётся реальная работа.

Обход нормальный, но диагноз сомнительный. Скорее всего, дело не в размере стека, во-первых, размер стека по умолчанию - несколько мегабайт (если не задавать ключей компиляции) и, во-вторых, переполнение стека это ошибка времени исполнения (если она возникает, для ifort помогает ключ /heap-arrays). Так что компилятору надо верить и смотреть, что он пишет, вероятно это ошибка компилятора.

P.S. Intel ifort (IFORT) 2021.1.2 20201208 под macOS тоже падает для 270000000 (Segmentation fault: 11), а GNU gfortran 13.2 нормально компилирует до размера 2147483647, после чего выдаёт Error: Integer too big for its kind, но при задании размеров 1000000000_8 (integer*8) и более нормально собирается. Что-то у Intel с созданием секций объектного файла размера больше 2 Гб не ладится.
